# Dynamically changing the ViewModel of a View in an MVVM, MEF implementation

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mvvm, mef

I have a usercontrol that i want to use throughout my Silverlight MEF MVVM solution.
I want to be able to link it up with one of a number of ViewModels depending on which module i am in. What this control does is list the records of a given entity so i can Add, Edit or Delete. I realized i would be using this control in multiple locations - to update several lookup tables, so i decided to make it's ViewModel dynamic. As seen below, I am using the Galasoft MVVM plugin.

```
if (!GalaSoft.MvvmLight.ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
            {
                // set DataContext
                DataContext = PluginCatalogService.Instance.FindSharedPlugin(ViewModelTypes.ViewModelMT, PluginType.ViewModel);
                _viewModel = (ViewModelMT)DataContext;
            }
```

My question is how can i dynamically change from ViewModelMT to ViewModelCT to allow me to independently display lookup tables e.g. Maintenance Types and Contract Types on an instance of this same usercontrol? I took a look at the Viewmodel locator, but I'm still not sure how to get this done.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is really a ViewModel thing. It's more of a Service problem.

Your ViewModel for the control will not change but you'll dynamically slot in the required service to maintain your list. ie. MaintenanceTypeService and ContractTypesService will implement IListMaintenanceService which exposes an list of items and Add,Delete and Edit commands.